# Oracle AWS RDS support

Tags: web8, content-manager, cm-db

Does SDL Web 8 support Oracle on AWS RDS as the CM database? I know the documentation mentions the following cloud databases:

1. Microsoft Azure SQL Database
2. AWS RDS-MSSQL 2014

But there is no mention of Oracle AWS support.

Comment: "Does SDL Web 8 support Oracle on AWS RDS as the CM database?" -- No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there is no mention in the Web 8 documentation of Oracle on AWS for the Content Manager database, and Content Data Store, is that this combination is not tested and therefore not supported.

If you want to try it, you are always free to do so, but if you encounter any issues, you are basically on your own. If the issue found is reproducible on any of the supported platforms, it will be fixed on the supported platforms, and such a fix might also be helpful on your unsupported platform, but there can be no guarantees.

Comment: You will likely hit issues with Distributed Transactions. AWS RDS doesn't support those and Oracle tends to promote to Distributed Tranactions sooner than SQL Server.